# Suggestions for an iOS mobile apps writing platform?

Tags: ios

I recently began studying mobile apps development and wonder if anyone has a good suggestion for an iOS compiler software?

Comment: What's wrong with using Xcode from Apple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path of least resistance, in my mind is using the compiler that comes with XCode. You can find it on the Mac App Store [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12)

Comment: Thanks JayL for the input. It's nice to see that some people can actually take the time to answer a genuine question with an honest answer.